# Connectedness and open mapping theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Open mapping theorem requires connectedness of domain area as following example indicates:

$B_a(r)$ denotes the open disk of center an and radius $r$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

Let $f:U:=B_0(1)∪B_2(1)→ \mathbb{C}$ be $f(z)=z$ on $B_0(1)$, $f(z)=1 $ on $B_2(1)$.

The f is clearly a non constant holomorphic function. But its image is $B_0(1)∪{1}$. This is not open.

**Question:**
where is the connectedness condition essentially necessary in a proof of the theorem?

Comment: What do you think? Do you know the proof of this theorem?